# How to set connection timeout to MQ queue manager in WebSphere 9.0.0.3

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am currently working on an application on WebSphere sending messages to an remote MQ which is set up by Client Definition Table.

I want to simulate a situation that when the Queue Manager is denied to be reached, a timeout error with 30s will be thrown.

I have set the timeout to 30s in both Session connection pool settings and MQ connection setting in WebSphere. I have also set receive-timeout property to be 30s  in the spring-integration jmsOutboundGateway. None of them have taken effect. The server in the end threw a Global Transaction timeout after 120s which is the default value.

I have used iptables REJECT rule to block the outgoing connection to the Queue Manager destination.

Comment: What is the `HBINT` value of the `SVRCONN` channel you connect to as well as the `CLNTCONN` channel in your `CCDT`.  The negotiated `HBINT` will be the highest value of the two.  The timeout is based on 2 times the `HBINT` if the `HBINT` is less than 60, otherwise it is `HBINT` + 60.  The default value on both a `SVRCONN` and `CLNTCONN` is 300, this means you end up with a 360 second (6 minute) timeout.  Set it to 15 seconds on both the remote `SVRCONN` channel and the `CLNTCONN` channel in the `CCDT` to obtain a 30 second timeout.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for your reply. Could I override the HBINT value without re-generate a new CCDT?

Comment: If you download the mq client v8 or higher it has a runmqsc command that can be used to alter it.

Comment: @JoshMc I have modified the `HBINT` to 15 and the request still hung for around 6-7mins. , and I have tired to modify `KAINT` to 15 and found no success. Would there be some configuration in WebSphere would override the heart beat interval setting. thanks.

Comment: Read my first update.  As I stated it takes the highest value between the `SVRCONN` on the queue manager and the `CLNTCONN` in the `CCDT`.  You would need to ask the queue manager admin to set the SVRCONN down to 15 as well.  There is no way to override this, it can never be less than the queue manager value.